# Align div next to two other grouped div's

Tags: css, alignment, html

How can I get that yellow box aligned like on the picture? I tried some stuff with table cells but it kinda destroyed everything. I also played a bit with the float conditions but the results were horrible too. Can you help me?

[image: Sketch of wanted result.]

Here's my code: 
**HTML**

```
<div class="job_board">

  <div class="job_box">

    <span class="job_title_working_field"> <!-- Just made that span for grouping but it's unnecessary. -->
      <div class="job_title"><h1>Product Development <span class="light">(m/w)</span></h1></div>
      <div class="working_field">Fahrzeugtechnik · Mechatronik · Maschinenbau</div>
    </span>

      <div class="slide_button"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.light {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.job_box {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 50px;
  background-color: #082730;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.working_field {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

span.job_title_working_field {
  table-cell;
}

.slide_button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qqz4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.slide_button` is within an element, you would simply relatively position the parent element:

```
.job_box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    background-color: #082730;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
```

And then absolutely position the yellow `.slide_button` element at the top/right - relative to the parent.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwgns/)

```
.slide_button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

If you look at the above example, you will notice that a horizontal scrollbar is present. If you want to remove this, use [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) in order to include the padding within the `.job_box` element's dimension calculations.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sEUk6/)

```
.job_box {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

It's also worth noting that I removed the default `8px` margin on the `body` element.. `body{margin:0}`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the markup order a little and updated the css

you are combining too many styles: `table-cell` + `absolute` + `float` don't mix well

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/3Qqz4/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="job_board">
    <div class="job_box">
        <div class="slide_button"></div>
        <div class="job_title_working_field">
            <div class="job_title">
                <h1>Product Development <span class="light">(m/w)</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="working_field">Fahrzeugtechnik · Mechatronik · Maschinenbau</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.light {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.job_box {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #082730;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family:"Helvetica", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    height: 120px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.job_title h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
.working_field {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
.job_title_working_field {
    padding: 30px 50px;
}
.slide_button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    float: right;
}
```